# Avoiding DAO Cross Access

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao

I am building a simple Spring + Hibernate app and I have the following models:

```
 Link ( id, url, title )
 History ( link_id, report_time, number_of_likes )
```

In my Main method I have something like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      ApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"spring.xml"});
      ...

      ((LinkDao) context.getBean("linkDao")).updateAll(date);

      ...
    }
```

This app runs every 30 minutes; goes through to the **LINK** table and records the number of Facebook likes at that moment in the **HISTORY** Table.

Now the problem is that I need to insert a record into **HISTORY** table from within the updateAll(Date date) method which is located inside ***LinkDaoImpl*** but I can't access the ***HistoryDaoImpl*** from ***LinkDaoImpl*** unless I pass the context to ***LinkDaoImpl***. Also If I include:

```
 @OneToMany
 List<History> history
```

Inside Link model, Hibernate creates an extra **HISTORY_LINK** table which is unnecessary.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not understanding why your History table is being saved inside of a method that is only supposed to be for accessing Link table data can you explain why that is. You should really reconsider that design. The history table being saved by a LinkDaoImpl hides a side effect of the LinkDaoImpl's updateAll, as well as this function is doing more than one thing.

Comment: @MarquisBlount Well, LINK table also has fields like NUMBER_OF_FB_LIKES,... I call updateAll method to update LINK table first but *also* I store the same value in HISTORY table along with a timestamp so later I can generate graphs...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `mappedBy="link"` in the `@OneToMany`. When you use relationship `@ManyToOne` , mapping uses `@JoinColumn` by default, but in `@OneToMany` you have to specify owner of the relationship

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to extract some of your logic contained in linkDao.updateAll to a service class.  The service class can do the cross model work, and leave your DAOs to only modify the tables they are supposed to.  Then you inject both DAOs into your service class.

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate will always create a new table between the entity relationship when you use @OneToMany annotation, even though you don't see the real use for it.

So, you should try a @OneToOne annotation in this case, or maybe just accept the new table created by the Hibernate.

Comment: No, not always. If you add `@JoinColumn(name = "link_id")`, it will map the association with the link_id join column.

Comment: Great, thanks for the correction. So based on your suggestion, I think it's better to use the @JoinColumn annotation, instead of trying another relationship mapping.